# Jquery Animation Delay not running correctly

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to delay an animation and I have tried both the Jquery attrbute and the setTimeout javascrip and neither have worked for me. The code is connecting to a CSS id and the running. I appreciate any help anyone can give me, I have included the code below. Thanks ahead of time

This is the original

```
$(function () { 

  $('#floatingbar').css({height: 0}).animate({ height: '50' }, 'slow'); 

});
```

This is how I applied the delay

```
$(function () {

  $('#floatingbar').css({height: 0}).delay(2000).animate({ height: '50' }, 'slow');  

});
```

Please post or contact if more inforamtion is needed

Comment: Could you define "not running correctly" more precisely?  Does the animation not run at all? Does the animation occur too soon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The delay is for the FX-Queue. If this is empty ... so on.

Try this:

```
 $('#floatingbar').animate({height: 0}, 0).delay(2000).animate({ height: '50' }, 'slow');
```

Comment: When I talk about the delay not running correctly I mean that the animation will not start with the delay in place.